# Evaluate iterator in python

Tags: python

I have a lazy iterator/generator `a` which is doing some side-effect on each iteration and I don't care about the values that it produces. What is the most idiomatic way to evaluate the side effects? Of course, I can simply do:

```
for _ in a: pass
```

But it seems rather ugly.

Comment: That's probably the least bad strategy, as generators with side effects aren't very idiomatic Python in the first place.

Comment: Better solution is don't write a lazy iterator with side effects

Comment: True, but in my case, the iterator comes from a library, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you give more context? It's likely there's another approach that would be altogether more idiomatic. Note: [*"Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular for loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful)."*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)

Comment: maybe filter or reduce?

Comment: @Ajurna Both of those are even worse, since they're pointlessly calling a function on each unwanted item yielded by the generator. (And in Python 3 `reduce` needs to be imported from functools).

Comment: on filter you could do something like filter(lambda x: False, iterator).

Comment: If the generator always yields truthy values: ``all(a)``.  If it always yields falsy values:  ``any(a)``.

Comment: @Ajurna: Sure, or `filter(lambda x: None, iterator)`, but it still has to call that lambda on each item, and calling a Python function isn't particularly fast (because each call has to create an execution frame object), so that imposes extra overhead on what's required to simply iterate over the items in the iterable.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, those techniques are concise, and `all` / `any` _iterate_  just as efficiently as `for`, but they still have to perform a boolean test on each item. However, I'm pretty sure that test is done via code running at C speed, so it _should_ be more efficient than performing a Python function call, as required in Ajurna's suggestions. But it's still more work than the simple `for` loop. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the recipe for the function `consume()` in [itertools recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Esentially, it recommends to do:

```py
collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
```